# How can I stick ListFooterComponent to the bottom of the screen?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a `FlatList` component, consisting of 3 sections:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <FlatList
        ListHeaderComponent={Comp1}
        ListFooterComponent={<Comp2 style={{ flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}/>}
        renderItem={Comp3}
        contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
    />
</View>
```

By default, the `ListFooterComponent` will render right after the `ListHeaderComponent`, if `data.length` is 0. 
I need to render it at the bottom all the time.

One workaround I've found so far is to provide an empty view for `ListEmptyComponent`. In this case, it looks fine, until I add at least one item - then it sticks to the top again.

Is it possible to attach `ListFooterComponent` to the bottom by default?

[image]

The blue color is the `FlatList`, the red color - `ListFooterComponent`

Comment: An other workaround is to render your FlatList as `flex:1`, but not directly on it. You can wrap your FlatList in a View with `flex:1` and then pass `contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}` as prop to FlatList. Does this fit your request?

Comment: it seems actually how it is right now :) the `FlatList` size seems perfect, the only thing that is wrong - the `ListFooterComponent`. I will update the code for better clarity

Comment: Ok I just understood your problem, sorry, and I'll think to a solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it needs to be on the bottom of the screen at all times, you can wrap the separate parts in a ScrollView

```
  render() {

    return (
      <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Comp1/>
        <FlatList
          style={{flex: 1}}
          renderItem={Comp3}
        />
        <Comp2/>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
```

Comment: yeah, it's an option, but in this case, it won't scroll with the rest of the view when its contentSize is bigger than the size. I want this still to happen. Does it make sense?

Comment: Indeed that's right, I see if I can think of a solution

Comment: I found a solution. I wrapped `Comp1`, `FlatList` and `Comp2` inside of the `scrollView`. if you get the idea - just rewrite your answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: Ah yes good idea! But I don't want to take credit for an answer I didn't come up with myself ;-)

Comment: Since you accepted anyway I will rewrite it for future reference ;-)

Comment: Uhm, I'm not sure wrapping a `FlatList` in a `ScrollView` does not cause any scroll problem on some devices, but ok

Comment: @Milore It works, I use it all the time. The scrollEnabled prop of the FlatList can be set to false when it's inside a ScrollView

Comment: a flatlist inside a scollview.... why?

Comment: @loekTheDreamer haha right, don't do this! It's been almost 5 years since I wrote this answer ...

Answer (score 1):

Before rederising your View, a good idea is to set your height according to the size of the screen. Something like:

```
const {height} = Dimensions.get ('window');
```

The View would look like this:

```
<View style = {{flex: 1, height: height}}>
```

Add position: **'relative'** to the View:

```
<View style = {{flex: 1, height: height, position: 'relative'}}>
```

Then add ListFooterComponentStyle to FlatList:

```
    ListFooterComponentStyle = {{
    backgroundColor: '# ccc',
    position: 'absolute,
    width: '100%',
    bottom: 0
}}
```

Show a complete example **function component**:

```
const {height} = Dimensions.get('window'); //capture the screen size

  return (
  <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1,height:height,backgroundColor:'#f5f5f5', position:'relative'}}>
  <FlatList 
        data = {YOUR_DATA}
        renderItem = {renderItem}
        keyExtractor = {item => item.idItem}
        numColumns = {2} // Divide list items into 2 columns (optional)
        onEndReached = {LOAD_MORE_DATA}
        onEndReachedThreshold = {0.1} //0.1 = 10%
        ListFooterComponent = {YOUR_COMPONENT_FOOTER}
        ListFooterComponentStyle={{
          backgroundColor:'#ccc', 
          position:'absolute',
          width:'100%', 
          bottom:0
        }}
      />
  </SafeAreaView>
  )
```

Answer (score -1):

add flexGrow: 1 to contentContainerStyle of Flatlist
add flexGrow: 1 to ListFooterComponentStyle of Flatlist
add flex: 1 and justifyContent: "flex-end" to View of container used in ListFooterComponent

```
<FlatList 
    contentContainerStyle = {{flexGrow: 1}}
    listFooterComponentStyle = {{flexGrow: 1}}
    listFooterComponent = {()=>(
           <View style={{
               flex:1,
               justifyContent: "flex-end"
           }}>
               ...Component you want at bottom
           </View>
    )}
/>
```