# React-Native FlatList takes more space than needed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, react-native-flatlist

I have a simple compoenent set up as to demonstrate my issue.

I have a base component `BaseScreenCenterTop`

```js
const BaseScreenCenterTop = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, props.style]}>
      {children}
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    paddingVertical: 30
  },
})
```

and my main component:

```js
<BaseScreenCenterTop>
  <View style={{backgroundColor: 'green', height: 30, width: '100%'}}>
  </View>
  <View>
    <FlatList
      data={doc.items}
      renderItem={({ item }) => renderItem(item)}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    />
  </View>
  <View>
    <Button
      title="Test"
    />
  </View>
</BaseScreenCenterTop>
```

The result I get is:

[image: Actual screen render]

And I want the FlatList to get the full height, but still have the Button visible at the end.

I tried many things to fix this, but it seems that the FlatList just sets its height to the maximum it can get until the end of the view, ignoring that there is stuff after it.

Thank you!

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54310081/16593275) can helps you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I stick ListFooterComponent to the bottom of the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54309242/how-can-i-stick-listfootercomponent-to-the-bottom-of-the-screen)